# IntegrityError at /station/Add/ (1048, "Column 'user_type_id' cannot be null")

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create new station using generic views
**when i try without user forigen key** I received this error
IntegrityError at /station/Add/
(1048, "Column 'user_type_id' cannot be null")

**if i tried without user_type and submit button cilck form automatic refresh and same clean**
Here is my code: station/views.py

```
class StationCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Station
    fields = ('station_name', 'station_address','connectors','status', 'start_time','end_time','open_day', 
                'state', 'city', 'area', 'user')
    template_name = 'owner/add_station.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

```
class Station(models.Model):    
STAUTUS_CHOICE = (
    ("ACTIVE", "ACTIVE"),
    ("INACTIVE", "INACTIVE")
    )
DAY_CHOICE = (
    ("MONDAY", "MONDAY"),
    ("Tuesday", "TUESDAY"),
    ("WEDNESDAY", "WEDNESDAY"),
    ("THURSDAY", "THURSDAY"),
    ("FRIDAY", "FRIDAY"),
    ("SATURDAY", "SATURDAY"),
    ("SUNDAY", "SUNDAY"),
    ("ALL DAY", "ALL DAY")
)
station_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
station_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
station_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
connectors = models.CharField(max_length=50)
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STAUTUS_CHOICE, default="ACTIVE")
start_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
end_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
open_day = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=DAY_CHOICE, default="ALL DAY")
# give_feedback = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
deleted = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)
```

`here is my code: add_station.html`

```
 <form method="post" action="" novalidate>
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                            

                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.station_name|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.station_address|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.connectors|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.status|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.start_time|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.end_time|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.open_day|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.state|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.city|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                                                {{ form.area|as_crispy_field }}
                                            </div>
                                                
                                            <button type="submit" class="w-full rounded-full bg-red-gradient p-3 text-white font-bold hover:ring">Add Station</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

Comment: can you share `model`?

Comment: i share it station model @HemalPatel

Comment: Share your `User` model